# Why JobScheduler is not working as expected

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I am using JobScheduler to run the job every 15 mins. But It is not working as expected. Here I attached my code.

```
public class WorkScheduler extends JobService {

    private static final String TAG = "Jobschedulerexample";
    private boolean jobCanceled = false;
    private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        Log.d(TAG,"Started at ==> "+ sdf.format(new Date()));
        Log.d(TAG,"Job Started");
        doBackgroundWork(jobParameters);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled before completion");
        jobCanceled = true;
        return true;
    }

    private void doBackgroundWork(final JobParameters params) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " + i);
                    if (jobCanceled) {
                        return;
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Job finished");
                Log.d(TAG,"Ended at ==> "+ sdf.format(new Date()));
                jobFinished(params, true);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

My utility class for Job service

```
public class WorkSchedulerUtility {

    private static final int JOB_ID = 123;
    private static WorkSchedulerUtility mInstance;
    private final int REFRESH_INTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000;

    private WorkSchedulerUtility(){

    }

    public static WorkSchedulerUtility getInstance(){
        if(mInstance == null){
            mInstance = new WorkSchedulerUtility();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private static final String TAG = "Jobschedulerexample";

    public void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, WorkScheduler.class);

       /* JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setPeriodic(REFRESH_INTERVAL)
                .build();*/

        JobInfo info = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, componentName)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .setBackoffCriteria(REFRESH_INTERVAL, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .setMinimumLatency(1000 * 6)
                .build();

        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int resultCode = scheduler.schedule(info);
        if (resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduled");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Job scheduling failed");
        }
    }

    public void cancelJob(Context context) {
        JobScheduler scheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        scheduler.cancel(123);
        Log.d(TAG, "Job cancelled");
    }

}
```

I planned to run the job for every 15 mins. But it is not start job every 15 mins. I will attach the output.

> Started at ==> 15:10:49  Ended at ==> 15:10:59  Started at ==>
>   15:25:59  Ended at ==> 15:26:09  Started at ==> 15:56:10  Ended at ==>
>   15:56:20  Started at ==> 16:41:44  Ended at ==> 16:41:54

I don't know why it is not working for every 15 mins. And also I want to start the job at specific time. For example every day at 8o'Clock. How to achive that using JobSceduler.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager)?

Comment: I will check that.

Answer (score 0):

JobScheduler is not guaranteed to run your job every 15 minutes, but when it sees fit. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45980135/android-jobscheduler-jobservice-not-working).